# Redux структура loading & error

Tags: reactjs, redux

Как организовать loading & error в redux initialState? Постоянно видел, что в initialState есть один loading и error. Но как быть с разными страницами и компонентами, которым нужен свой loading и error? Для каждой страницы и компонента создавать отдельные состояния? Типа: **initialState:{loadingUsers:false, errorUsers:null, loadingPosts:false, errorPosts:null}?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь стоит понимать на сколько взаимосвязаны Ваши ***users*** и ***posts*** сущности. Они независимы друг от друга или, к примеру, каждому юзеру будет соответствовать  свой массив постов и т.д.? В любом случае стоит создавать отдельные состояния, как Вы и написали. Но, если эти или другие сущности более независимы друг от друга, то Вам, стоит "разбить" ваш главный редьюсер на несколько более мелких, и с помощью [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) из пакета redux  собрать их воедино:

*src/reducers/pages.js:*

```
const initialState = {
      pages: [];
      pagesErrors: null,
      pagesLoading: false,  
    }
    
    export default function(state = initialState, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
       ....
      default:
      return state;

     }
   }
```

*src/reducers/users.js:*

```
const initialState = {
      users: [];
      userErrors: null,
      usersLoading: false,  
    }
    
    export default function(state = initialState, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
       ....
      default:
      return state;

     }
   }
```

*src/reducers/index.js:*

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import page from './pages'
import user from './users'

export default combineReducers({
  pages,
  users
})
```